# How representative are Pauli errors of the complete set of errors that can occur on a quantum computer?

Tags: programming, hardware

We know that Pauli errors (=channels?) can be simulated efficiently on a classical computer.

How representative are Pauli errors of the complete set of errors that can occur on a quantum computer?

Is this a pure representation convenience issue or is the Pauli error assumption hiding something?